# Is the MIME type 'image/jpg' the same as 'image/jpeg'?

Tags: file, mime-types

Pretty simple question but can't seem to find it anywhere online. I'm trying to make a program that depending on the file type will give me the extension.

Comment: AFAIK there is only the type "image/jpeg" http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html#mime-types-list

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23424399/jpg-vs-jpeg-image-formats

Comment: Must be late night confusion then. I'm going to just give it a try with "image/jpeg".

Comment: Try also this read: https://www.keycdn.com/support/difference-between-jpg-and-jpeg

Answer (score 797, accepted):

No, `image/jpg` is not the same as `image/jpeg`.

You should use `image/jpeg`. Only `image/jpeg` is recognised as the actual mime type for JPEG files.

See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3745, https://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/ .

Serving the incorrect Content-Type of `image/jpg` to IE can cause issues, see http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2609-internet-explorer-aborts-images-with-the-wrong-mime-type.htm.

Comment: THE principal problem caused by this is that Safari will open an image link in Preview instead of in the browser window because it thinks it's an unknown image type (which technically, it is).

Comment: If you develop iOS apps using WkWebview, the image will display as text on iOS 15 if you use image/jpg for the MIME type. Using image/jpeg resolves the issue.

Comment: Worth to mention than `.jpg` and `.jpeg` are extensions for same format type: JPEG. The reason `.jpg` exists is that earlier versions of Windows require three letter extension. For MIME there is no such limitation, so there is only one mime type for JPEG images: `image/jpeg`. This mime does not exists: `image/jpg`.

Answer (score 63):

**tl;dr** There is no MIME type `image/jpg`; there is `image/jpeg`.  However, there is much variation in official documented mappings between files with file name extension `.jpg` and MIME types. But in practice, nearly all software handles image files named `*.jpg` in an expected manner

This particular topic is confusing because the varying association of file name extension associated to a MIME type depends which organization created the table of file name extensions to MIME types.  In other words, file name extension `.jpg` could be many different things, "officially" (but in practice is always a JPEG image).

For example, here are three "complete lists" and one RFC that with varying *JPEG Image format* file name extensions and the associated MIME types.

- [sitepoint.com *The Complete List of MIME Types*](https://www.sitepoint.com/mime-types-complete-list/) <sup>[archived](http://archive.fo/TvfIs)</sup>

  - `.jfif`, `.jfif-tbnl`, `.jpe`, `.jpeg`, `.jpg` → `image/jpeg`
  - `.jfif`, `.jpe`, `.jpeg`, `.jpg` → `image/pjpeg`
- [freeformatter.com *MIME Types List*](https://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html#mime-types-list) <sup>[archived](http://archive.fo/PHi1Q)</sup>

  - `.jpeg`, `.jpg`  → `image/jpeg`
  - `.jpeg`, `.jpg`  → `image/x-citrix-jpeg`
  - `.pjpeg` → `image/pjpeg`
- [IANA *Media Types*](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml)  <sup>[archived](http://archive.fo/X0pWM)</sup>
  (this document uses phrase "*Media Types*" instead of "*MIME Types*")
  (this document lists "*names"*, not "*file name extensions*")

  - `jpg` not mentioned
  - `jpeg` → see *RFC 2045* (no mention), see *RFC 2046* → `image/jpeg`<sup>[13](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-4.2)</sup>
  - `JPEG` → `video/JPEG`
  - `jpeg2000` → `video/jpeg2000`
  - `jpm` → `image/jpm` (*JPEG 2000*)
  - `jpx` → `image/jpx` (*JPEG 2000*)
  - `vnd.sealedmedia.softseal.jpg`  → `image/vnd.sealedmedia.softseal.jpg`
- [RFC 3745 *MIME Type Registrations for JPEG 2000 (ISO/IEC 15444)*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3745) **

  - `.jpg` file extension not mentioned
  - `.jpeg` file extension not mentioned
  - `.jp2`, `.jpg2` → `image/jp2` (*JPEG 2000*)<sup>[9](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3745#section-4.1)</sup>
  - `.jpf`, `.jpx` → `image/jpx` (*JPEG 2000 ISO-JPEG2000-2 encoded image data*)<sup>[10](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3745#section-4.2)</sup>
  - `.mj2`, `.mjp2`  → `video/mj2` (*Motion JPEG 2000*)<sup>[11](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3745#section-4.3)</sup>
  - `.jpm`, `.jpgm` → `image/jpm` (*JPEG 2000 profiles and
    extensions*)<sup>[12](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3745#section-4.4)</sup>

These "complete lists" and RFC do not have MIME type `image/jpg`!  But for MIME type `image/jpeg` some lists do have varying file name extensions (`.jpeg`, `.jpg`, …).  Other lists do not mention MIME type `image/jpeg`.

Also, there are different types of *JPEG Image format*s (e.g. *Progressive JPEG Image format*, *JPEG 2000*, etcetera) and "JPEG Extensions" that may or may not overlap in file name extension and declared MIME type.

Another confusing thing is *RFC 3745* does not appear to match *IANA Media Types* yet the same RFC is supposed to inform the *IANA Media Types* document. For example, in *RFC 3745* `.jpf` is preferred file extension for `image/jpx` but in *IANA Media Types* the name `jpf` is not present (and that IANA document references *RFC 3745*!).

Another confusing thing is *IANA Media Types* lists "names" but does not list "file name extensions". This is on purpose, but confuses the endeavor of mapping file name extensions to MIME types.

Another confusing thing: is it "*mime*", or "*MIME*", or "*MIME type*", or "*mime type*", or "*mime/type*", or "*media type*"?

The most official *seeming* document by IANA is surprisingly inadequate. No MIME type is registered for file extension `.jpg` yet there exists the odd `vnd.sealedmedia.softseal.jpg`. File extension`.JPEG` is only known as a `video` type while file extension `.jpeg` is an image type (when did lowercase and uppercase letters start mattering!?).  At the same time, `jpeg2000` is type `video` yet *RFC 3745* considers *JPEG 2000* an `image` type!  The IANA list seems to cater to company-specific jpeg formats (e.g. `vnd.sealedmedia.softseal.jpg`).

### In summary...

Because of the prior confusions, **it is difficult to find an industry-accepted canonical document that maps file name extensions to MIME types (and vice-versa), particularly for the JPEG Image File Format**.

---

###### ** RFC 3745 reads

> This document is not related to the definition of the MIME sub-type
> image/jpeg, which is partly defined by [ISO-JPEG-1], and partly by
> the file format specification defined in [JFIF].

- Specification [`JFIF`](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/jfif3.pdf) (*JPEG File Interchange Format*) does not mention any MIME types or file name extensions.
- Specification [`ISO-JPEG-1`](https://www.iso.org/standard/18902.html) (*ISO/IEC 10918-1:1994*) requires a fair amount of money to view.

---

Related question "[*List of ALL MimeTypes on the Planet, mapped to File Extensions?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735659/list-of-all-mimetypes-on-the-planet-mapped-to-file-extensions)".

Comment: usually there is only ONE source describing the regarding standard, not 4 (!).
RFC is a good entry point!

Answer (score 22):

For those it might help, I use [this list](https://www.sitepoint.com/mime-types-complete-list/) as a reference to define my content-type when I have to deal with images on my app.

It says that jpg extension can be declared with `Content-type : image/jpeg`

There isn't any `image/jpg` attribute for content-type.

Answer (score 7):

The important thing to note here is that the mime type is *not* the same as the file extension. Sometimes, however, they have the same value.

https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml includes a list of registered Mime types, though there is nothing stopping you from making up your own, as long as you are at both the sending and the receiving end. Here is where Microsoft comes in to the picture.

Where there is a lot of confusion is the fact that operating systems have their own way of identifying file types by using the tail end of the file name, referred to as the extension. In modern operating systems, the whole name is one long string, but in more primitive operating systems, it is treated as a separate attribute.

The OS which caused the confusion is MSDOS, which had limited the extension to 3 characters. This limitation is inherited to this day in devices, such as SD cards, which still store data in the same way.

One side effect of this limitation is that some file extensions, such as `.gif` match their Mime Type, `image/gif`, while others are compromised. This includes `image/jpeg` whose extension is shortened to `.jpg`. Even in modern Windows, where the limitation is lifted, Microsoft never let the past go, and so the file extension is still the shortened version.

Given that that:

1. File Extensions are *not* File Types
2. Historically, some operating systems had serious file name limitations
3. Some operating systems will just go ahead and make up their own rules

The short answer is:

- Technically, there is no such thing as `image/jpg`, so the answer is
  that it is not the same as `image/jpeg`
- That won’t stop *some* operating systems and software from treating
  it as if it is the same

**While we’re at it …**

Legacy versions of Internet Explorer took the liberty of uploading `jpeg` files with the Mime Type of `image/pjpeg`, which, of course, just means more work for everybody else. They also uploaded `png` files as `image/x-png`.