# display Content-Type: application/jpeg result on webpage

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js

I have an API request URL, which will automatically download and save a QRcode image from the browser.

Its Content-Type is application/jpeg, and its form is like this:

```
application(websiteURl)/egs?cmd=gen_qrcode&customer_id=123&name=abc
```

Before the slash is my app's URL, and then it is the request's key and value pairs.

When I post this on the browser, it will automatically download a QRcode jpg.
However, I want to get the image to jpg(or another image type) to display on my web application and don't wanna save it.

When I use PostMan and save the file, it give me the header informations:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.jpg";
Content-Type: application/jpeg;
```

I am using javascript and Vue,
I wonder if there is a way to prevent the autosave and display the image.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can find online, `application/jpeg` is not a valid `Content-Type` header. You should use the according header `image/jpg` or `image/jpeg`.

See [Is the MIME type 'image/jpg' the same as 'image/jpeg'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33692835/is-the-mime-type-image-jpg-the-same-as-image-jpeg) and https://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/

EDIT:
You may also want to try to manually set (or unset) your `Content-Disposition` header.

Comment: I do not wrote this `application/jpeg` and `Content-Type`, I wanna know may I change this in my javascript?

Comment: What kind of application are you using as a server?

Comment: I am using Vue and Node.js for frontend, backend is java spring.

Comment: Well if you have the URL for the image, you could use an '<img />' element to refer to the image URL?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I have tried the src of  '<img />' element, and it just give me a broken photo. I think it's not a valid type of image, so the '<img />' element can not read it.

Comment: That is basically the same issue as with the header probably. Maybe you should find a node library to generate QR-images for you so you have more control over them.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I will search the information about that.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the invalid Content-Type you're using, `Content-Disposition: attachment` tells the browser to save it instead of showing it. Remove that.

Comment: The response is from another website, could I change the `Content-Disposition` at my side(client side)?