# Getting empty request body in server while sending image in POST request

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm sending image from android app on server an by some reasons I can't figure out on server I'm receiving empty request body. Sending image with a following code:

```
val serverUrl = "http://192.168.56.1:8080/recognize/get_text_from_image"

    val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .build()

    val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream)
    val byteArray = stream.toByteArray()
    val encodedImage: String = encodeToString(byteArray, DEFAULT)

    val requestBody: RequestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*jpg"), encodedImage)

    val request: Request = Request.Builder()
        .url(serverUrl)
        .post(requestBody)
        .build()
```

edit 1:
Cant make it work like in comment:
[image]

Server side:

```
 Router baseRouter = Router.router(vertx);
        Router apiRouter = Router.router(vertx);

        baseRouter.route("/").handler(routingContext -> {
            HttpServerResponse response = routingContext.response();
            response.putHeader("content-type", "text/plain").end("Heeloo Vert.x!");
        });
        //recogizeText();
//        apiRouter.get("/get_text_from_image").handler(this::getText);

        baseRouter.mountSubRouter("/recognize", apiRouter);

        vertx.createHttpServer()
                .requestHandler(baseRouter::accept)
                .listen(8080, result -> {
                    if (result.succeeded()) {
                        System.out.println("completed");
                        startFuture.complete();
                    } else {
                        startFuture.fail(result.cause());
                        System.out.println(result.cause().getLocalizedMessage());
                    }
                });

        apiRouter.route(HttpMethod.POST, "/get_text_from_image").handler(rc -> {
            System.out.println("request came...");
            try {
                JsonObject json = rc.getBodyAsJson();
                System.out.println(rc.data().size());
                System.out.println(json);
                System.out.println(rc.getBody());
            }catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error while getting BodyAsJson...");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Debugger info:
as I see image is inside content, but I cant find it on server
[image]

rc on server side info from debugger:
[image]

Comment: could you post your server-side API code for get_text_from_image?

Comment: You should attach a debugger and evaluate each of those variables to see where the data gets erased before reaching the `requestBody` variable. This might help you investigate your problem.

Comment: I also agree with the other comment, could totally be a server side issue.

Comment: Also, you don't need to encode byte array to string, you could simply use: `byteArray.toRequestBody("image/jpg".toMediaType())`

Comment: @GouseMohiddin, thanks for reply, add server side code

Comment: @Qunata, thanks for reply, tried to use byteArray.toRequestBody("image/jpg".toMediaType()) but IDE can't handle it, add screenshot in post.

Comment: what are you getting in the rc?

Comment: in rc everything is null or if it list their length are zero, I also added debugger info for requestBody from app

Comment: @GouseMohiddin, added screenshot with rc info from debugger

Comment: Try this : Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bao);
        byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();
        String imageConverted = Base64.encodeToString(ba, Base64.DEFAULT);

Comment: @GouseMohiddin, it worked thanks, but still getting nulls on server

Comment: rc in your server code is null?

Comment: I think you should check rc.rawBody

Comment: Check here to see what I meant, https://pastebin.com/YLAXjszZ.
Also, this is not relevant to your problem but the Kotlin way to do things :)

Comment: @Qunata, I see, thanks a lot)

Comment: @GouseMohiddin, no, rc is not null, I can;t find image inside rc, that is the problem

Comment: Also why do you have an `'*'` in your media type? I see two valid options: `'image/*'` or `'image/jpeg'`

Comment: `'image/jpg'` is not a valid MIME type: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33692835/is-the-mime-type-image-jpg-the-same-as-image-jpeg

Comment: @Qunata,  I already fixed it by using code u provided with link above, but still cant find image on server in request

Comment: I observed you server side code and noticed that you are building a JSON object from your image data? Can you add a watch expression on `rc.data()` on the debugger and check what value it holds? Is the line `System.out.println(rc.getBody());` ever getting executed ?

Comment: @Qunata, rc.getBody() is null