# Describing a GET request returning a file in OpenAPI 3.0

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator

I am writing an OpenAPI 3.0 specification and have an endpoint returning a file. Now I found documentation on the website of Swagger but that's about a POST request: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/multipart-requests/.

There's also another StackOverflow question with zero responses about my question, so I will give it another go.

How does one write a specification for a GET request where a file should be returned?

I currently have the following:

```
      responses:
        '200':
          description: ok
          content:
            multipart/form-data:
              schema:
                type: object
                description: The multipart object containing the file bytes
                properties:
                  file:
                    type: string
                    format: binary
                    description: Bytes of the file
```

But I think this is mostly for POST request, to upload a file. Does anyone know what it should be?

Comment: What kind of file does your endpoint return - text, PDF, ZIP, audio, arbitrary binary file, ...?

Comment: Either a pdf or an image in jpeg or png

Answer (score 2):

In OpenAPI 3.0, a response containing a PDF, PNG, or JPG file is described as follows:

```yaml
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A PDF file, PNG image, or JPG image
          content:
            application/pdf:
              schema:
                type: string
                format: binary
            image/png:
              schema:
                type: string
                format: binary
            image/jpeg:  # 'jpeg' not 'jpg', see https://stackoverflow.com/q/33692835
              schema:
                type: string
                format: binary
```

Comment: What about `MP4` file?

Comment: @none MP4 is also `type: string` + `format: binary`. Just use the correct media type (e.g. [video/mp4](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/codecs_parameter)) under the `content` key.

Comment: I tried it, but I still get `Unrecognized response type; displaying content as text.`

Comment: Make sure your server response has the correct `Content-Type` header, e.g. `Content-Type: video/mp4`.

Comment: Yes, it has, it works fin from `Postman` for example.